# Pytest dict equality preserving order and nice diff output (python-3.7+)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

As of python 3.7, `dict` is [guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html) to be insertion ordered. I have a unit test using pytest where I would like to compare two dicts but with order of elements in mind.

My application will never run on python older then 3.7 so backward compatibility is not an issue for me.

**Question**

Is there any possibility to compare regular `dict`s, preserving order and nice diff output in **pytest**?

**My unsuccesful tries**

```py
a = {'x': 1, 'y': {'u': 3, 'v': 4}}
b = {'y': {'v': 4, 'u': 3}, 'x': 1}

assert a == b
```

This assertion passes, but I don't want it to. These dicts are equal but with wrong order.

I can convert everything to `OrderedDict` but it is

- ugly code
- produces ugly pytest diff output

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def deep_ordered_dict(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        value = OrderedDict(value)

        for k, v in value.items():
            value[k] = deep_ordered_dict(v)

    if isinstance(value, list):
        for k, v in enumerate(value):
            value[k] = deep_ordered_dict(v)

    return value

a = {'x': 1, 'y': {'u': 3, 'v': 4}}
b = {'y': {'v': 4, 'u': 3}, 'x': 1}

assert deep_ordered_dict(a) == deep_ordered_dict(b)
```

Comparing it as JSON is not better

- produces ugly pytest diff output

```py
import json

a = {'x': 1, 'y': {'u': 3, 'v': 4}}
b = {'y': {'v': 4, 'u': 3}, 'x': 1}

assert json.dumps(a, indent=2) == json.dumps(b, indent=2)
```

Comment: Even though dictionaries now preserve order, it's still recommended not to depend on it. So it feels like a problem with your design if you have a test to ensure it.

Comment: Python dicts preserve order but the order is still arbitrary as they are implemented as hash tables.  So to you, the order matters, but to the computer it doesn't.

Comment: `list(a.items()) == list(b.items())`?

Comment: @Barmar who recommend it? As of python 3.7 dict insertion order is documented language guarantee. So, I can surly depend on it.

Comment: @jasonharper unfortunately, solution with `list` is not much better then my solution with `OrderedDict`. It still produces ugly pytest diff output.

Comment: @j123b567 I was thinking of the 3.6 recommendation, when it was just a CPython feature. But since there's very little control of the ordering (it's just insertion order, there's no `move_to_end` like `OrderedDict`), it still seems like a poor choice.

Comment: My question is about python 3.7 and newer. I have updated the question so it is really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Even though dictionaries are required to preserve insertion order as of Python 3.7, for backward compatibility equality comparisons are order-independent. This is one of the documented differences between `dict` and `OrderedDict`, so if you want order-sensitive comparisons you should use the latter.

Comment: Yes, but it is ugly in **pytest** for large and nested `dict`s. As I mentioned in the question. I'm aware of the `OrderedDict` but it produces ugly pytest outputs.

Comment: You can write a function that recursively converts all the dicts to `OrderedDict`.